# Macro to insert a row above any existing row that has data in it

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have tried to manipulate some VBA to make this work but, I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

I want to write a macro that inserts a new row above any row with data, then copies the data from cell 1 and 2 into that new row.

I put a picture of what I have and a picture of what I want to have

Additional Photos:

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G1Px.png)
[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlQfU.png)

Here is the code I used but I need it to continue down the line:

```
 Sub InsertRowandCopyCell1and2()
'
' InsertRowandCopyCell1and2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
    Rows("78:78").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A79:B79").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A78").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Rows("78:78").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
        .TintAndShade = -9.99786370433668E-02
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Rows("92:92").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A93:B93").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A92").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Rows("92:92").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
        .TintAndShade = -9.99786370433668E-02
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Rows("96:96").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A97:B97").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A96").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Rows("96:96").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
        .TintAndShade = -9.99786370433668E-02
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post the code attempt (in its current form) that you do have. You'll receive more effective help if you show your coding efforts, rather than effectively asking someone to code for you from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may actually be tricky. If you try to iterate a set of rows while inserting a new row at the same time, you'll end up having an endless loop. The solution is to store data rows in a collection first and then iterate on that collection while inserting rows and copying data. See if the example below works for you.

Update: Changed the logic to only insert the empty row if first two columns have value. See if this works.

Starting state:

[image]

Code:

```
Sub insertRows()

    ' first you have to store all the rows in a collection,
    ' because if you'll iterate while adding rows your loop
    ' will never end
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim cRows As New Collection
    For Each rw In ActiveSheet.[a1:e11].Rows
        ' only include rows that have first and second cells non-empty
        If Len(Trim(rw.Cells(1))) > 0 And Len(Trim(rw.Cells(2))) > 0 Then
            cRows.Add rw
        End If
    Next

    ' now iterate the immutable collection of rows and copy data
    Dim rng As Variant
    For Each rng In cRows
        rng.EntireRow.Insert
        rng.Cells(1).Cut rng.Cells(1).Offset(-1)
        rng.Cells(2).Cut rng.Cells(2).Offset(-1)
    Next

End Sub
```

End state:

[image]

Comment: I added 2 more photos. I am actually adding a row above. The reason I need to add a row above is because I need to write definitions of list names AND all the codes inside the list. So if you look.. I need to add the row so I can write the definition of the list name and then the business user can read list definition and then all the code definitions.

Comment: @EthicalMotive Updated to work on the example you provided. I still don't understand from your description where should "defintions of list names and all the codes" be copied from, but this should give you a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be able to get the core of the code by recording a macro. Just turn on recording, Insert the necessary row & copy the values down to the new row. Then you'll just need to genericize it. Give that a shot and if you're still having trouble, post the code as you have it for more detailed guidance.

Update: Here's how I'd tweak the code you posted

```
Sub InsertRowandCopyCell1and2()
'
' InsertRowandCopyCell1and2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
Dim i as Long
Dim ws as worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'change to the correct index or use the sheet's name

'Setup to iterate through the rows. NOTE: I'm assuming your data starts in row 2 & that
'    the data is continuous in Column C (i.e. if C is blank for a row, there is no data
'    from that row down) adjust the macro accordingly
i = 3
Do While ws.Range("C" & i - 1).value <> ""
    'Check if the row has data in columns A & B
    If ws.Range("A" & i - 1).value <> "" And ws.Range("B" & i - 1).Value <> "" Then
        'Prior row has data, insert a new row BELOW the row being checked (thus why we
        '    start on row 3 & look at row i -1
        ws.Rows(i & ":" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        'We've just created a new row i, which we now need to move the data from row i - 1 down into
        ws.Range("C" & i - 1 & ":E" & i - 1).Cut
        ws.Range("C" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        'The row we need to check next WAS row i, but due to the insert, it's now row i + 1,
        '    so we simply increment i by 2 (thus skipping looking at row i, the row we just created)
        i = i + 2
    Else
        'Row does not indicate an insertion is necessary, simply  move to the next row
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

I did strip out the format altering code, since I wasn't following the logic on when to do that, but you can add it back by simply wrapping it with an `If`statement that has the right condition.

Side bar: Avoid using `Select` & `Selection.` wherever possible as it significantly slows your code.

Comment: I posted the code I used in the question. I couldn't figure out how to format it right.